# When testing localized strings in an app, what does zero over double zero represent?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm currently testing localized strings in an app and an Action Alert is showing a character I'm not too familiar with.  Does the zero over double zero character mean there isn't enough room in the UI?

This is currently the Swedish setting on the iPhone: 
[image]

Comment: That is the "per mille sign": http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2030/index.htm. But what is your actual string and the corresponding localization?

Comment: You are not connected to the Internet is what it should say.

Comment: Where does the string come from *in your code?*

Comment: This is a situation of black box testing so I'm not sure if I can answer your question in regards to seeing the actual code.  Or are you asking what would this say in English translation?

Comment: Yes, I am asking for actual code (Swift code and strings file), ideally a [mcve]. Without that we can only *guess* what causes the issue.

Comment: Its okay because this has been a huge lesson as I've never seen the per mile symbol in an app.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swedish**

> Du r inte unsluten till internet

means, **You are not connected to the internet**

Comment: Per Martin's comment above, if a Swedish user saw the "per mille sign", would this be an issue?

Comment: How does this explain the ‰ character?

Comment: I think that it should read Du'r, but, as often happens, the apostrophe was replaced by a random character.

As to why that's happening (which I think is the original question about the UI), I am unprepared to answer.

Comment: No, there won't be any issue. It gives the same meaning

Comment: Who/what would replace the apostrophe by a "random character"? Sorry, but this does not explain anything.

Comment: I'm Swedish, and if I saw the per mille sign instead of "**ä**" in some app I used, contrary to what SivajeeBattina writes above, I _would_ refer to this as an issue/bug. It should read "Du **är** inte ansluten till internet.".

Comment: @dfri: My guess would be an encoding problem, but without concrete code ...

Comment: @MartinR yes probably, and that mighty fine screenshot wont help us to debug that :)